# App is supported by 0 (zero) devices on Play Store

Tags: android

I tried about anything I found on stackoverflow but Google Play continue to say that my App is supported by 0 Devices.

Here my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer">

    <!--
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
     -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false" />
    <!-- <uses-feature android:name="com.android.hardware.camera2.full" android:required="false"/> -->
    <!-- <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" /> -->

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"   />

    <compatible-screens>

        <!-- small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />

        <!--Only hdpi and xhdpi for normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />

        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />

        <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />

    </compatible-screens>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityMain"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityAdd"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityCamera2"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"></activity>
        <activity android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityExplore"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityOptions"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityCamera1">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.RuntimePermissionActivity"
            android:theme="@style/squarecamera__CameraFullScreenTheme.NoUI" >
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here the Gradle App:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        StuffDrawer {
            keyAlias '*******'
            keyPassword '**********'
            storeFile file('C:/***********')
            storePassword '***********'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 15
        versionName '1.15'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.StuffDrawer
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.StuffDrawer
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.38'
}
```

As you can see I tried to add all screen sizes, to declare camera2 in different ways and to remove the USES-SDK from the Manifest because it was in conflict with Gradle.

My app needs both Camera1 and Camera2 API, when usupported CAMERA2 api is deactivated programmatically.

Please, any suggestion? Many thanks

Edit: Let me add that I recently changed the project name but I don't know if this would work or not.

Edit: I tried to remove all permissions and uses-feature, same problem.

I anlyzed with APK Analyzer and this the resulting manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="15"
    android:versionName="1.15"
    package="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer"
    platformBuildVersionCode="25"
    platformBuildVersionName="7.1.1">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:resizeable="true" />

    <application
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f080115"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f060021"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f030000"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:roundIcon="@ref/0x7f030001">

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f080115"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityMain"
            android:screenOrientation="7"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f080115"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityAdd"
            android:screenOrientation="7"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f080116"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityCamera2"
            android:screenOrientation="7"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f080115"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityExplore"
            android:screenOrientation="7"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f080115"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityOptions"
            android:screenOrientation="7"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12" />

        <activity
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityCamera1" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f08016e"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.RuntimePermissionActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have a RED point here:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

And the error is: URI is not registered

Edit: After updating Android Studio to latest stable release here the new APK analyzer, where permissions and uses are come back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="15"
    android:versionName="1.15"
    package="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer"
    platformBuildVersionCode="25"
    platformBuildVersionName="7.1.1">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="false" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:resizeable="true" />

    <application
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f080115"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f060021"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f030000"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:roundIcon="@ref/0x7f030001">

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f080115"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityMain"
            android:screenOrientation="7"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f080115"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityAdd"
            android:screenOrientation="7"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f080116"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityCamera2"
            android:screenOrientation="7"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f080115"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityExplore"
            android:screenOrientation="7"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f080115"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityOptions"
            android:screenOrientation="7"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="0x12" />

        <activity
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.ActivityCamera1" />

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f08016e"
            android:name="rapture.engineering.stuffdrawer.RuntimePermissionActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Remove the <supports-screens> and <compatible-screens> sections. By default an app is compatible with every screen until you add these.

Comment: Thanks, I already know this. I have only tried to overcome the error but no results.

Comment: Use APK analyzer tool with your generated APK and inspect the final merged manifest file. Also check if you have native binaries in the APK.

Comment: @BladeCoder I'm searching but i doubt I have the required abilities to decompile or reverse engineering my app :-( I am not able to check for native binaries...

Comment: You don't need to decompile anything, just check the presence or absence of native binaries. If native binaries are present, then your app will be restricted to the supported architecture(s).

Comment: Your merged manifest looks OK, though I don't see any <uses-permission> or <uses-feature> tag in it. The point was to check if a library you use added required features to the manifest, which would restrict the app to run only on some devices.

Comment: @BladeCoder: FinallyI found some examples of native code and no, i have not in my code...
I also updated my Android Studio and updated the main question.

Comment: Sorry, I've seen other similar questions popping up lately. The newly deployed Developer Console seems to have issues at the moment.

Comment: This won't change your play store visibility, but there's no "android.hardware.camera2" feature. Camera2 exists on all devices running Android 5.0 or later; there are features for the hardware support level of a device, such as https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA_LEVEL_FULL , but you likely don't care about those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a UI issue with the Google Play Developer console at the moment that it is showing 0 supported devices when uploading new APK updates.

It is highly likely that there is no issue with you app.

Comment: Thanks buddy you're right. 10.936 supported devices today! Forgive me, this happened to me on the launch day!!